# What's the fastest endpoint to check for a new medium.com post?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

Is it

https://medium.com/@blah/latest?format=json

I'm only concerned with new article titles.

I know they have an RSS feed, but wouldn't that be slower?

https://medium.com/feed/@blah

I know they have an API but I don't think it allows you to check for new posts and even if it did, there would be rate-limiting.